# using square root objects in Z3 c++

Tags: c++, z3

I am using Z3 with the C++ APIs. I have to solve a system of equations that include square root terms. how can I use square root in Z3 C++?
temporarily, I replace something like this:

> s.add(x == sqrt(4));

with this:

> s.add(x*x == 4);

but in some cases, it doesn't give the right results, so I am asking is there a way to do the sqrt directly?

Comment: These are not mathematically equivalent. The first one forces x to be +2, second one allows +2 and -2 as solutions for x.

Comment: @FBergo actually I have to use both positive and negative values as the solution for "x", but I was asking if there is another simpler way to handle it. I have much complicated equations in my system

Comment: What's the type of `x`? If they are Reals, then Z3 does support infinite precision values. If they are integers, what you are doing is the best you can get.